# ScrollView & Linear Layout not displaying elements right

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview, android-scrollview

Okay, so I created a ScrollView and inside it two linear layouts with elements. 
When I go into design mode I see this(left picture), but when I run the app on my cell I get this (right picture):

[image]

The white space between the bar and the picture is what I want to remove. I don't understand how it got like that because the design view shows how it should look like. I'm using Drawer Menu also.

This is my xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tvrdjava"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />

        <!-- Ovde pocinju kartice (Cards) -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.ivanp.cardivantestdva.MainActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#607D8B"
                android:layout_height="55dp">


                <!-- Naslov kartica -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Tvrdjava"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView52"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="test"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/datumprikaz"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

UPDATE: This is my activity main xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

This is my activity_main_drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:id="@+id/menu_top">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tvrdjava"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Tvrdjava" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bubanj"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Bubanj" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_cegar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Čegar" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_celekula"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Ćele kula" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_podesavanja"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Podešavanja" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_onama"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="O Nama" />
</group>
```

Comment: Please attach your DrawerLayout xml too.

Comment: Are you using the same resolution in the android studio's layout editor? You can select the device to render the layout on. The LG G3 has a big resolution btw. I think your problem is around the adjustViewBounds and cropToPadding. Since the device resolution is big, the imageview tries to keep your image's ratio and you end up with the extra white space

Comment: Have you checked in any of the other devices ? is it showing same in all the scenario ?

Comment: Design view shows the same result in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. The LG G3 uses xxxhdpi if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it !
The problem was the default margins in values/dimens.xml
Just changed this:

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_height">160dp</dimen>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

To this:

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_height">160dp</dimen>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
```